# Can heat transfer from one object to another if they both have the same temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, carnot-cycle

I do not understand how the heat is transferred between the reservoir and the gas in stages *1* and *3* of the **Carnot Cycle** (the *isothermal parts* of the cycle). From what I know, If two objects have the same temperature, then there will not be any heat transfer.

I have seen some of the explanations but those included lots of concepts that I have not learned like **Entropy**, **Le Chatelier's principle**.

Can someone help explain to me **intuitively** using **basic concepts**? Your help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: *stages 1 and 3* Are you referring to the isothermal parts of the Carnot cycle?

Comment: @Gert yes, I am.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From what I know, If two objects have the same temperature, then there
> will not be any heat transfer.

And you would be absolutely correct. Heat is energy transfer due solely to temperature difference. This is why all real heat transfer processes require a temperature difference and all real heat transfer processes are irreversible.

But you can make those temperature differences infinitesimal so that the temperature difference in the limit approaches zero. That is the case for the reversible isothermal expansion and compression processes in the Carnot Cycle. It is also the reason why the Carnot Cycle is impractical. The smaller the temperature difference the lower the rate of heat transfer, all other things being equal. The lower the rate of heat transfer the longer process takes. In the limit when the temperature difference approaches zero it takes an infinite amount of time to complete the process.

So although the Carnot cycle is the most efficient in producing work for a given heat input, the rate of work done (power output) for the Carnot cycle approaches zero in the limit. As has been said, the Carnot cycle is an ideal construct in terms of a limit on the maximum possible efficiency of any heat engine cycle.

Someone once said if you put a Carnot engine in your car you would get fantastic fuel economy, but pedestrians would be passing you by.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

There is some confusion here: in order to be isothermal you need to exchange heat. When you start the transformation, the gas changes its temperature momentarily (you are compressing it or expanding it so it will try to accomodate that by changing *both* his pressure and temperature) . This generates a small temperature difference with the reservoir, so heat flows in order to bring it back to the temperafure of the reservoir, which is the original starting temperature. Then you compress/expand a bit more, and again  you have a small temperature difference and heat flow. If you do this slow enough, the gas will at every step re-equilibrate to its original temperature accommodating the change by a change in pressure according to $PV=nRT$. So the heat flow you have doubts about is precisely what keeps the temperature constant, which otherwise would change.

So there *are* temperature differences but small and momentary ad at each step the gas equilibrates at its normal $T$. If these differences in T are small enough, we neglect them and treat it as isothermal!

Answer (score 0):

temperature is particle intensity moving back and forth. If one object has a higher temperature than another than the vibrations in that object are more frequent than in the colder object. When the two objects come into contact the vibration energy is transferred until both objects have identical vibration frequencies acting on the particles that make them up. It's about energy.

One source of energy will transfer itself to another until both are in equilibrium (or are equal). At equality transfer is impossible because they are both at the same level.
Energy transfer in a static environment. But if they were moving, then you would have to factor in other elements.

Answer (score -1):

Without a difference in thermal states from which to establish *a flow of energy,* mechanical work cannot be extracted.

You've defined your system at it's Entropic Maxim: Thermal-Equilibrium.

Without external energy, it'll stay there forever.

Comment: The topic is the Carnot cycle, where there are two heat reservoirs at different temperatures. Work can be extracted. The OP's question is about each of the "isothermal" parts of the cycle.